# I have kernel image for Qemu but i dont know for what machine it has configured to emulate? (for example vexpress-a9 or virt .,)

Tags: qemu

I have kernel image for Qemu but don't know for what machine it has configured to emulate? (for example vexpress-a9 or virt .,)

How do I find the configured machine by using kernel image?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working QEMU command line that goes with the kernel, you can look at what the -M/--machine option it uses is. Otherwise, if you have the kernel .config you can see which machines the kernel was built with support for. Otherwise, you need to ask whoever it was that built the kernel what they intended it to be used for, or just throw it away and get or build one that you know does work.